# « De te venir en aide à titre gracieux » ou « pour te venir en aide à titre gracieux »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Je n’ai plus les moyens financiers **de** te venir en aide dans tes travaux de rénovation à titre gracieux, et cela en apportant mon savoir-faire en charpenterie-menuiserie; j’ai des obligations comme tout le monde et pour m’en acquitter, il me faut un travail rémunéré.

Je n’ai plus les moyens financiers **pour** te venir en aide dans tes travaux de rénovation à titre gracieux, et cela en apportant mon savoir-faire en charpenterie-menuiserie; j’ai des obligations comme toute le monde et pour m’en acquitter, il me faut un travail rémunéré.

D’autres tournures/formulations à proposer?

**Il s’agit de la reformulation d’une question que j’ai posée hier et que j’ai mal exprimée. À la demande d’un contributeur de *French Language*, je pose à nouveau la question avec les modifications apportées tout en laissant intacte la première version, qui a déjà reçu une réponse.

Comment: *, et cela en* me parait alourdir la phrase et introduit une dissonnance car instinctivement on l'applique à toute la proposition qui se trouve avant la virgule, depuis "Je n'ai plus les moyens de..." Je me débarrasserais de la virgule et du "et cela" pour juste garder *en* dans une continuité fluide avec ce qui précède directement.

Comment: Et aussi : déplacer *à titre gracieux* : "de te venir en aide dans tes travaux de rénovation en apportant à titre gracieux mon savoir-faire..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***De*** est de meilleur style :

> *Je n’ai plus les moyens financiers **de** te venir en aide [...]*

Avec ***pour***, tu aurais pu écrire:

> *Je n'ai plus les moyens financiers **nécessaires/requis pour** (pouvoir) te venir en aide [...]*